# Update a part of text with quotes

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I change value in table:

`name=\"kjname\" type=\"email\`

on

`name=\"kjname\" type=\"text\`

When i try this request:

`UPDATE`table`SET`column`= REPLACE(column, "email", "text") WHERE column LIKE '%name=\%"%kjname\%"% type=\%"%email\%' ESCAPE '\'';`

Replaces all "email" on "text". But I need to change only in the line where there is: `name=\"kjname\" type=\"email\`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then I suggest doing a regex replacement with `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET column = REGEXP_REPLACE(col, 'name="([^"]+)" type="email"', 'name="$1" type="text"');
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Comment: Unfortunetly. MySQL version - 5.7.21-20

Comment: You really need regex replacement to do your update in a safe and precise way.